# service httpd status output?

Tags: services, httpd

On a Linux web server running httpd service, the below is what you get from issuing the following command:

`service httpd status`

Is anyone intimately familiar with these states?

```
__C__W_KW__W....K._K..KW.....W..R.W.............................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................

   Scoreboard Key:
   "_" Waiting for Connection, "S" Starting up, "R" Reading Request,
   "W" Sending Reply, "K" Keepalive (read), "D" DNS Lookup,
   "C" Closing connection, "L" Logging, "G" Gracefully finishing,
   "I" Idle cleanup of worker, "." Open slot with no current process
```

I want to know the difference between states like C vs G , and S vs R, and . vs _ ?